# Can't manage to save a created image with PIL with the right color

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I've got this function, that gets a video, extracts a frame and save it as an image, if i use cv2.write it works flawlessly (but I cannot manage to make it work with py2exe or Pyinstaller), so I'm trying PIL now, when I save the frame with PIL the image colors are wrong, usually greens and reds have a blue tincture.

```
from PIL import Image
# import cv2

def getThumbnail(video):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    cap.set(1, 150)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    im = Image.fromarray(frame)
    print (im, im.format, "% dx%d" % im.size, im.mode)
    im.save(video.split(".")[0] + '.mp4' +'.jpg', icc_profile=im.info.get('icc_profile'))
    # cv2.imwrite(video.split(".")[0] + '.mp4.jpg', frame)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! I found the solution in:http://blog.extramaster.net the problem was the way cv2 and PIL treat the image codification.

```
def getThumbnail(video):
    #Image._initialized = 2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    cap.set(1, 150)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    array = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    im = Image.fromarray(array)
    print (im, im.format, "% dx%d" % im.size, im.mode)
    im.save(video.split(".")[0] + '.mp4' +'.jpg', "JPEG", icc_profile=im.info.get('icc_profile'))
```

Since I have found little documentation I leave this here and hopefully it would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Add the second parameter - `"JPEG"`:

```
im.save(v_files[i].split(".")[0] + '.mp4.jpg', "JPEG", icc_profile=im.info.get('icc_profile'))
```

Comment: Same result, according to the manual:
 format
– Optional format override.  If omitted, the format to use is determined from the filename extension.  If a file object was used instead of a filename, this parameter should always be used.

So even if I don't add "JPEG" it still should use the right parameter as the ending is .jpg

Comment: Did you try omit the third parameter (`icc_profile=...`)?

Comment: Yes, I added it because this metadata viewer: http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi said that it hasn't color-space metadata and no embedded color profile so I though maybe the problem was that it missread the data, but it makes no difference whatsoever...